# ng-if/ng-hide doesn't get updated on real time on HTML page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, typescript

I need some help in implementing a small change in angularJs with typescript. I basically need to change the text of a button for 3 seconds from the time it is being clicked, and revert the original text after 3 seconds are over. For this, I have created 2 html elements (buttons). I have applied ng-if directive for this purpose. Basically my aim is is as soon as the first button is clicked, it should get hidden and the other button should be displayed for just 3 seconds. After 3 seconds, the first button should come again.

Following are the 2 html buttons:

```
<div class="action">
                            <button class="configure-link" ng-if="!showPhoneNumber" ng-click="testAudio()">Listen</button>
                            <button class="configure-link" ng-if="showPhoneNumber"> Calling {{phonenumber}}</button>
</div>
```

As we can see, 'showPhoneNumber' is a boolean variable. When it is false, first button should be visible, and when it is true, second button should be visible. Following is the way I am changing the value of this boolean variable in typescript file:

Typescript:

```
scope.showPhoneNumber = false;
scope.testAudio = () =>{
scope.showPhoneNumber = true;
                setTimeout(function () { scope.showPhoneNumber = false }, 3000);
}
```

As soon as I click the first button, showPhoneNumber becomes true and first button gets hidden and I can see the second button. However the problem is, it is taking much more than 3 seconds (around 20 seconds) to get reverted and showing the first button again. Why ng-if is not getting binded from true to false after 3 seconds. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can you please help?

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using `setTimeout` function and not `$timeout` Angular service. Angular doesn't know that something has changed on scope until $apply is called.
Possible fixes:

- call scope.apply after setting scope.showPhoneNumber to false in your timeout callback
- use [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) Angular service

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, setTimeout won't notify Angular and that's why is best practice to use $timeout instead. However, you can still keep your old code, just add `$apply();` after `scope.showPhoneNumber = false;` like this:

```
setTimeout(function () { 
  scope.showPhoneNumber = false;
  $apply();
}, 3000);
```

If you want to know why and when to use `$apply()`, have a look at this post: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html